How to re-render AuthProvider in react, after logging in
My project's authentication flow is:
AuthProvider encapsulates all routes,
AuthProvider has useEffect that calls a verifyToken API to check the token validity.
When user submits login form, token is set from backend, and the page navigate to protected route:
The protected route gets the authentication from AuthProvider that checks if the token is valid or not.
My issue is, before user logs in, the AuthProvider call the API and everything is set to false.
So, navigating to protected route send back to login.
I have to manually type domain/dashboard to force re render everything so that the AuthProvider once again sends the true valid data to protected route.
Here is my AuthProvier:
import { useVerifyToken } from "@/Auth/hooks/useAuthQuery";
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../hooks/AuthContext";


interface AuthProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
}
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const { data: validUserDetails, isLoading:verifyTokenLoading, isSuccess, isError } = useVerifyToken();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (validUserDetails && isSuccess) {
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
            sessionStorage.setItem('validUserDetails', JSON.stringify(validUserDetails));
        }
        else if (isError) {
            setIsAuthenticated(false);
            sessionStorage.removeItem('validUserDetails');
        }
    }, [validUserDetails, isSuccess, isError])

    console.trace(isAuthenticated)

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{isAuthenticated,verifyTokenLoading}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

Here is AuthContext:
import { createContext } from "react";

interface AuthContextValue {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  verifyTokenLoading: boolean;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextValue>({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  verifyTokenLoading: false,
});


Here is ProtectedRoute Component:
import Sidebar from "@/Common/pages/Sidebar"
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom"
import Spinner from '@/Common/Utils/Spinner'
import { useContext } from "react"
import { AuthContext } from "@/Common/hooks/AuthContext";

function ProtectedRoute() {
    const {isAuthenticated,verifyTokenLoading} =useContext(AuthContext);

    if (verifyTokenLoading) {
        return (
            <Spinner />
        )
    }

    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        return <Navigate to={'/auth/login'} replace />
    }

    return (
        <section className="flex">
            <section className="w-[23%] min-h-screen">
                <Sidebar />
            </section>
            <section className="w-full px-4 py-4 bg-tertiary/5 min-h-screen">
                <Outlet />
            </section>
        </section>
    )
}

export default ProtectedRoute

Here is my routes:
import {createBrowserRouter, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import Auth from './Auth/views/Index';
import LoginForm from './Auth/components/LoginForm';
import SignupForm from './Auth/components/SignupForm';
import ForgetPassword from './Auth/components/ForgetPassword';
import NotFoundPage from './Common/pages/NotFoundPage';
import ErrorPage from './Common/pages/ErrorPage';
import ProtectedRoute from './Auth/components/ProtectedRoute';
import Dashboard from '@/Dashboard/views/Index';
import MyProjects from '@/MyProjects/views/Index';
import Calendar from '@/Calendar/views/Index';

export const routes=createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path:'',
        element:<App/>,
        children:[
            {
                path:'auth',
                element:<Auth/>,
                children:[
                    {
                        path:'',
                        element:<Navigate to={'/auth/login'} replace/>
                    },
                    {
                        path:'login',
                        index:true,
                        element:<LoginForm/>
                    },
                    {
                        path:'signup',
                        element:<SignupForm/>
                    },
                    {
                        path:'forgetpassword',
                        element:<ForgetPassword/>
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path:'',
                element:<ProtectedRoute/>,
                children:[
                    {
                        index:true,
                        element:<Navigate to={'/dashboard'}/>
                    },
                    {
                        path:'dashboard',
                        element:<Dashboard/>
                    },
                    {
                        path:'myprojects',
                        element:<MyProjects/>
                    },
                    {
                        path:'calendar',
                        element:<Calendar/>
                    }
                ]
            }
            
        ],
        errorElement:<ErrorPage/>
    },
    {
        path:'*',
        element:<NotFoundPage/>
    }
])


Here is my APICalls using react query:
import { ApiManager } from "@/Common/Services/TaskItApi/ApiManager";
import { AuthEndpoints } from "@/Common/Services/TaskItApi/Endpoints";
import { useMutation, useQuery, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { SignUp } from "../components/SignupForm";
import { LoginData } from "../components/LoginForm";
import { toast } from "sonner";

export const useSignUp = () => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (data:SignUp) => {
      const response = await ApiManager.post(AuthEndpoints.signUp(), data);
      return response;
    },
    onError:(error)=>{
        toast.error(error.message)
    },
    onSuccess:()=>{
        toast.success('Account Registered Successfully')
    }
  });
};

export const useLogin = () => {
  const queryClient=useQueryClient();
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (data:LoginData) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey:['validUserDetails']})
      const response = await ApiManager.post(AuthEndpoints.login(), data);
      return response;
    },
    onError:(error)=>{
        toast.error(error.message)
    }
  });
};

export const useVerifyToken=()=>{
  return useQuery({
    queryKey:['validUserDetails'],
    queryFn:async()=>{
      const response =await ApiManager.get(AuthEndpoints.verifyToken());
      return response;
    },
    retry:0,
  })
}

export const useLogout=()=>{
  const queryClient=useQueryClient();
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn:async()=>{
      const response=await ApiManager.post(AuthEndpoints.logout(),{});
      return response;
    },
    onSuccess:()=>{
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey:['validUserDetails']})
      toast.success('Logout Successful')
    },
    onError:(error)=>{
      toast.error(error.message)
    }
  })
}


I could try, force re rendering the AuthProvider based on token changed.
I can't find a way to do that either.
